# Fill-In-Field suppress or close the prompt on Add

Tags: vba, ms-word

**What I am doing**
Via DDE I send to my word macro some field names.
With those field names the macro creates fields of type "wdFieldFillIn".
The current problem I am facing starts at the document.Fields.Add-Function.
Because each FillInField prompts the user to input a value. But I don't want the user to input a value now, instead at this point it should just create those fields without showing any prompt.

To simplify the scenario in the shown example, you see how I add one FillInField at the cursor selection.

```vb
Dim myRange As Range: Set myRange = Selection.Range
Dim FillInField As Field: Set FillInField = doc.Fields.Add( _
            Range:=selectedRange, _
            Type:=wdFieldFillIn, _
            Text:=fieldName)
```

**What I have tried so far:**

Sending Keystrokes via `SendKeys "{ESCAPE}"`
Result: fires to late, because the makro waits for the prompt.

Writing it as plain text: `{ FILLIN My_Fieldname \* MERGEFORMAT }`
Result: Not treated as a field.

**The prompt window:**
[image]

**Implemented Solution used**
This solution refers to @jonsson's answer and works for my use case.

```vb
Dim FillInField As Field: Set FillInField = Selection.Fields.Add(_
            Range:=insertRange, _
            Type:=wdFieldEmpty, _
            Text:=fieldName)
FillInField.code.Text = "FILLIN " & fieldName & " \* MERGEFORMAT "
FillInField.Result.Text = fieldExampleText
Set FillInField = Nothing
```

Resulting in a Fill-in-Field without prompting the user at the time it gets added.\

Comment: Did you think of using content controls instead of fields. You won't have these issues then.

Comment: @Ike Yes, I thought about content controls, but fill-in-fields are also compatible with LibreOffice. This made a lot of implementation in my c++-code quite easy.

Comment: @jonsson I just tested what you said, when *.Text=""* is ok, it adds an empty field in the doc indeed, however, what the questioner wants is **wdFieldFillIn** and the [Type property is read-only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.field.type) It is not possible to specify its value later, and when *.Text= "FILLIN My_Fieldname"*, it will still show the "prompt window" then.

Comment: @jonsson According to the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.field.type) (I gave the link before) and actually checked, once you've specified **Type=wdFieldEmpty** with the **Add** method, if you try to assign a new value to it later, you will get an error message during the compilation time that told you cannot assign a value to the read-only property.

Comment: @jonsson I don't understand what you are talking about, and I have limited knowledge of field objects. Why don't you make a code to check it out together? It is better, isn't it? Good night *(I'm in Taipei)* and nice to meet you.

Comment: @jonsson OK I'll try it late. If any questions I'll be back to comment here. THANK YOU.

Comment: @OscarSun I have tried jonsson's solution, and it worked for my use case. It doesn't prompt me anything while adding the field. The field seems to work correctly. I have added the implementation in my working code to the question.

Comment: @BaronvonHoot you accepted and set  *Type:=wdFieldEmpty,* It seems that you don't care that in this execution step, the Type must be *wdFieldFillIn* Well. I don't know much about this implementation, and I'm not sure what kind of operation you are trying to achieve. I'm just expressing my opinion. If you have been able to meet the current needs, then I am really happy for you; perhaps I have similar needs in the future, I will also come back to observe the reference. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AIUI you are trying to insert the FILLIN field without actually executing it, so that you can execute it later. BUt if that isn't the case, perhaps you could clarify.

If so, one way would be to insert it as an "Empty field type", then change its field code like this

```
Dim f as Word.Field
Set f = Selection.Fields.Add(wdFieldEmpty,"")
f.Code.Text = " FILLIN My_FieldName " ' or whatever code you actually need
Set f = Nothing
```

Then, when the field is actually executed (however that is done) it will behave as a normal FILLIN.

If you want the field to be inserted so that it has a result regardless of whether the fillin is executed or not, you need to do a bit more because for example

```
Dim f as Word.Field
Set f = Selection.Fields.Add(wdFieldEmpty,"")
f.Code.Text = " FILLIN My_FieldName " ' or whatever code you actually need
f.Result.Text = "the text I want in the result"
Set f = Nothing
```

will actually insert the text "after" the field result. But in that case all you really need to do is insert a field that *does* have a result, and change its code, e.g.

```
Dim f as Word.Field
Set f = Selection.Fields.Add(wdFieldQuote,"the text I want in the result")
f.Code.Text = " FILLIN My_FieldName " ' or whatever code you actually need
Set f = Nothing
```

@OscarSun raised the issue that the .Type property of a Word Field object is read-only, so you can't do

```
Dim f as Word.Field
Set f = Selection.Fields.Add(wdFieldQuote,"the text I want in the result")
f.Type = wdFieldFillin
```

as the compiler will flag the attempted assignment to a readonly property. And that is correct. IMO this observation deserves a bit of explanation.

If you use the following code things may become clearer:

```vb
    Sub insertfillin()
    Dim f As Word.Field
    Debug.Print "wdFieldQuote = " & CStr(WdFieldType.wdFieldQuote)
    Debug.Print "wdFieldFillin = " & CStr(WdFieldType.wdFieldFillin)
    Set f = Selection.Fields.Add(Selection.Range, WdFieldType.wdFieldQuote, "temp result")
    ' This should be the same as WdFieldType.wdFieldQuote
    Debug.Print "New field's type = " & CStr(f.Type)
    f.Code.Text = "FILLIN MyFieldName"
    ' This should be the same as WdFieldType.wdFieldFillin
    Debug.Print "Field type is now " & CStr(f.Type)
    Set f = Nothing
    End Sub
```

i.e. we haven't actually tried to assign to the f.Type so the compiler won't complain. Perhaps best seen from a programming point of view that changing the field's type is a side-effect of changing its code and that would presumably be forbidden if for example we were using a functional programming language.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid what you want is not possible, as long as you use the Fill-In field, because it is defined by default to run the message box (as you said "prompt window") to be entered by the user. You can only set the **default value** to be entered in VBA or in the user interface, the parameter is "**\d**" used in **Text** argument, but there is no setting to not display this message box.

```vb
fieldName = "\d """ '"" is what the default string value you want
```

Because this message box is opened as an exclusive form ( *modal* ), it will interrupt the execution of the VBA code. If you want to execute something else in VBA, maybe you can try to create a **UserForm** and set the **Timer event**, and enable it in the background before you execute the [**.Add**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.fields.add?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Dzh-TW%26k%3Dk(vbawd10.chm154140777)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue) method, UserForm, and then run **SendKeys** at the specified time. And as far as I know, multi-threaded cannot be implemented in VBA alone

You can refer to this article:

[Field codes: Fill-In field](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/field-codes-fill-in-field-aa773538-91ee-446a-9a58-1cff8db21d59)

[List of field codes in Word](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/list-of-field-codes-in-word-1ad6d91a-55a7-4a8d-b535-cf7888659a51)

Comment: This solution worked. But resulted in flashing popup windows, which appeared for a short time. Additionally, if the user was fast enough, he could still type something into the prompt.

Comment: @BaronvonHoot You mean using the UserForm TimerEvent and SentKeys methods? Could it shorten the Timer time **interval**, or open the userform in the background like setting the visible property as false or setting the open's argument to hide (ex. use the **Load** rather than use **Show** method to initiate the form. Maybe the  *popup window* you mean just that prompt window you want to Omit, and I've misunderstood.